# JQuery UI Autocomplete: Auto height does not respect maxHeight

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I would like my jQuery UI AutoComplete to have the dynamic window size containing the available options, but also to have a max height so that when there are a large number of options returned it does not take up the whole page.

When I have the following, the height is dynamic but maxHeight is ignored:

```
    .ui-autocomplete {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width:auto;
}
```

When I have the following, the height is not dynamic but maxHeight works:

```
    .ui-autocomplete {
    height: 250px;
    max-height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: what you have should be working. I can reproduce the results on the jQuery demo page. My guess is a CSS conflict somewhere. Check in your browsers dev tools to make sure that the CSS is getting applied. Try adding !important to the height rules (just to test, fix the css, don't just leave it important).

Comment: If you need avoid element goes out on the page: you can try : position: { my : "left top", at: "left bottom", collision: "flipfit" }, in autocomplete function : https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-position

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used TJ's great example ([http://jsfiddle.net/s6XTu/12/](http://jsfiddle.net/s6XTu/12/.)) for my code. But if you are using multiple autocomplete on your page you have to change some lines in the script. You have to use the "autocomplete("widget")" as reference.

```
    $('.ui-autocomplete').css('height', 'auto');
var $input = $(event.target),
    inputTop = $input.offset().top,
    inputHeight = $input.height(),
    autocompleteHeight = $input.autocomplete("widget").height(), // changed
    windowHeight = $(window).height();
if((inputHeight + autocompleteHeight) > (windowHeight - inputTop - inputHeight)) {
    $('.ui-autocomplete').css('height', (windowHeight - inputHeight - inputTop - 20) + 'px');
}
```

Comment: Note: event.target may not be the input if you're using a callback for suggestions. I *think* using 'this' is more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea here is to only apply a `height` or `max-height` if the contents of the  autocomplete widget is overflowing the `window`.  You can detect this with the following:

```
//Reset the height so the true height can be calculated.
$('.ui-autocomplete').css('height', 'auto');

//Get some values needed to determine whether the widget is on
//the screen
var $input = $('#the-id-of-the-input-node'),
    inputTop = $input.offset().top,
    inputHeight = $input.height(),
    autocompleteHeight = $('.ui-autocomplete').height(),
    windowHeight = $(window).height();

//The widget has left the screen if the input's height plus it's offset from the top of
//the screen, plus the height of the autocomplete are greater than the height of the
//window.   
if ((inputHeight + inputTop + autocompleteHeight) > windowHeight) {

    //Set the new height of the autocomplete to the height of the window, minus the
    //height of the input and the offset of the input from the top of the screen.  The
    //20 is simply there to give some spacing between the bottom of the screen and the
    //bottom of the autocomplete widget.
    $('.ui-autocomplete')
        .css('height', (windowHeight - inputHeight - inputTop - 20) + 'px');
}
```

In CSS you'll also need to set the `overflow` so that a scroll bar appears when the content of the `ui-autocomplete` doesn't fit in its container.

```
.ui-autocomplete { overflow: auto; }
```

I have a live example showing this here - http://jsfiddle.net/s6XTu/12/.

Comment: Thanks for this. One *very* minor note: In your fiddle you've used event.target to get the input. That doesn't work if the event that's causing the open didn't originate with the input. In my case I am getting the suggestions remotely so the event target is actually the request object. I changed it to 'this' which seems to be working so far.

Answer (score 2):

Dont put hieght
Just put max-height , it will work

```
.ui-autocomplete {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
cursor: default;
max-height: 145px;
overflow-y: auto; 
overflow-x: hidden;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

this solutionis working in my side.

```
.ui-autocomplete {
        overflow: auto;
        max-height: 150px !important;
    }
```

Check this Images.
[image]
[image]