# Jquery autocomplete exceeding height of document

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, absolute

I am using jquery autocomplete in my project. There is an issue with height of the autocomplete suggestions. The container is exceeding the height of document. The behavior is replicated in the fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/cq5kL/1/

```
.ui-autocomplete { overflow: auto; }
```

I tried giving `bottom:0` to .ui-autocomplete. It works when the data is more, but for 2-3 reocords, there is a huge block stretching till the bottom of document.
Please suggest how I can limit the height to the height of document irrespective or no. of records in the autocomplete suggestions list.

Edit: Already there is too much javascript in my page, I'd prefer a solution overriding the css classes

Comment: did you figure out how to do it? the solutions here present a largely empty menu area when there are 1 or 2 entries, instead of shrinking

Comment: check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299548/jquery-ui-autocomplete-auto-height-does-not-respect-maxheight/70665304#70665304

Answer (score 5):

Try to give the .ui-autocomplete a height. For example:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 300px;
}
```

See your updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cq5kL/2/

Comment: I don't want to fix the height. I want it to be fluid.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/cq5kL/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cq5kL/4/ happens if there are some other elements before the input

Comment: ps. It's `autocomplete`, spelling error on `autcomplete`

Answer (score 0):

the answer is here: [jQueryUI Autocomplete ComboBox Too Long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182766/jqueryui-autocomplete-combobox-too-long)

but in essence: set the `max-height` property

Answer (score -1):

For me the solution is similar Pataar's answer.

```
.ui-menu {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 300px;
}
```